# unity netcode and lobby, after host leaves lobby and lobby disappears from lobbies lists, clients stay in lobby indefinitely without any notification

Tags: unity-game-engine

im using netcode and unity lobby service

so as i said, if a host leaves the lobby by disabling app, crash or internet malfunction, lobby is destroyed after 30 seconds by unity service. but all clients inside lobby is not notified that server doesnt exist anymore.

i found solution how to migrate lobby to a new host, but host needs to be inside lobby/ online for that to happen.

does someone have a solution how to migrate lobby host to another player if original host suddenly disapears? or at wery least how to check by client if lobby is destroyed and load back to lobby list window

thank you